# Is the github API rate limit per user or per domain/ip address?

Tags: git, github, oauth, github-api, rate-limiting

Github document says:

```
For requests using Basic Authentication or OAuth, you can make up to 5,000 requests per hour
```

Is this limit per user, i.e. per access token, or per ip address?

For example, if I have 10 OAuth authorised users use my server app to access data from github api, is the limit from my server ip 5k or 5k x 10 per hour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two sentences immediately following the sentence quoted in your question [contain the answer](https://developer.github.com/v3/rate_limit/):

> For requests using Basic Authentication or OAuth, you can make up to
>   5,000 requests per hour. *For* ***unauthenticated requests***, *the rate limit
>   allows you to make up to 60 requests per hour*. ***Unauthenticated
>   requests are associated with your IP address, and not the user making
>   requests.***

Therefore rate limit for authenticated requests applies to the user account and not the IP address.

If you still doubt, you can check your rate limit status by looking at the `X-RateLimit-*` headers contained in the responses from [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting) or through the special [Rate Limit API](https://developer.github.com/v3/rate_limit/).